# MySQL Subquery - Max Amount

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am new to **subqueries**, and I am trying to understand why my regular query isn't returning the same result as this subquery. I am following this [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/) and it is the first "[Try it out](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-subquery/#1)" question. ->

**My query is:**

```
SELECT customerNumber,
       checkNumber,
       MAX(amount)
FROM payments
```

Comment: Your attempted query will return the maximum amount out of all the payments. But there is no guarantee on the value of customerNumber and checkNumber as data is basically stored in unordered fashion

Comment: That query you have is badly formed. I know MySQL accepts it and even runs it. The result is -- however -- quite random. You don't want that. If you have some column with `MAX()` and other ones without it you should **always** use `GROUP BY`. Always.

Comment: Since you're still learning, learn to use aggregation properly.  Your statement will not even run in any other dbms except for maybe `MySQL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you used aggregate function  `max()` so you are bound to use group by and your query will be like below

```
 SELECT customerNumber,
           checkNumber,
           MAX(amount)
    FROM payments
    group by customerNumber,
           checkNumber
```

Comment: Thank you Zaynul. For the future, would it be best practice to write my query like the one you provided or to start using subqueries?

Comment: @DEVLIFEE7 if it helps then please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

The query you are testing from the tutorial is different, it gets you the row with the maximun amount (just one row):

```
SELECT customerNumber,
       checkNumber,
       amount
FROM payments
WHERE amount = (
    SELECT MAX(amount) 
        FROM payments
);
```

And the query with the aggregation function gets the maximum amount for each combination of customerNumber and checkNumber (could be several combinations):

```
SELECT customerNumber,
           checkNumber,
           MAX(amount)
    FROM payments
    group by customerNumber,
           checkNumber
```

It all depends on what you want to get.